# How to solve this degenerate parabolic euqation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following equation

\begin{align*}
\label{linear-prandtl-transform-3}
\begin{cases}
& \partial_t \hat{w}(t, x, y) + \tilde{u(t, y)}\partial_x \hat w(t, x, y) - 2 \partial_y \left(\eta(t, y) \hat w(t, x, y)\right) - \partial_y^2 \hat w(t, x, y) =0, t >0,~~-\infty < x < + \infty, y>0, \\
& \hat w|_{t = 0}=\hat w_0,\\
& (\hat{w}_y + 2 \eta \hat{w})_{y=0}=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where  $\tilde{u}(t, y), ~~\eta,~~\eta_y$ are bounded function.

Is there some finished work or book about this equation?

Merci bien.

Comment: This does not seem degenerate?